# Show that if Y is transcendental over a field K, and F is a field with $K\subset F\subset K(Y)$ and $K\neq F$ then Y is algebraic on F

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I have the following problem:

> Show that if Y is transcendental over a field K, and F is a field with $K\subset F\subset K(Y)$ and $K\neq F$ then Y is algebraic on F

I know there are infinite fields of such type, for example $K[Y^i]$ has Y as an algebraic element $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$
However I don't know how to prove this in the general case. This question was proposed in my Galois theory exam last year. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean $K(Y)$ instead? There are no invertible elements but elements of $K$ in $K[Y]$.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks I've changed it now

Comment: Hint: take $R(Y)=\frac{P(Y)}{Q(Y)} \in F$ that is not a constant. Can you find a polynomial $\Pi(T) \in F[T]$ such that $\Pi(Y)=0$?

Comment: $K(Y) \cap \overline{K} = K$. Either $F \subset \overline{K}$ and $F= K$ or $F \supsetneq K$ and $F$ contains some $P(Y)/Q(Y) \in K(Y), \not \in K$.

Comment: @Mindlack How do you know you can find such a $R(Y)$

Comment: Because $K \subset F$ and $K \neq F$.

Comment: @Mindlack Oooooh

Comment: @Mindlack So $F(T)=R(Y)\cdot Q(T)-P(T)$ is an acceptable choice? I'm not sure, because it's not clear that the coefficients of $P(T)$ and $Q(T)$ are on $F$

Comment: The coefficients of $P(T)$ and $Q(T)$ are in $K \subset F$.

Comment: @Mindlack you can't believe how hard I just palmed my face with my hand haha. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be seen as an extended comment on the 'comments", though thought and work of my own:

We recall that since $Y$ is transcendental over $K$, $K(Y)$ is the field of rational functions in $Y$ with coefficients in $K$; the quotient field of $K[Y]$.

Thus if

$K \subsetneq F \subset K(Y), \tag 1$

the elements of $F$ are themselves non-constant rational functions in $Y$, with coefficients from $K$.  We may thus represent any element

$u(Y) \in F \tag 2$

as

$u(Y) = \dfrac{p(Y)}{q(Y)}, \tag 3$

where

$p(Y), q(Y) \in K[Y]. \tag 4$

We note that

$u(Y)q(x) - p(x) \in F[x]; \tag 5$

that is, $u(Y)q(x) - p(x)$ is a polynomial in the indeterminate $x$ with coefficients in the field $F$.

When we write (3) in the form

$u(Y)q(Y) - p(Y) = 0, \tag 6$

we see that $Y$ is a zero of the polynomial (5); thus $Y$ is algebraic over $F$.